# Azure Cache for Redis Simple Set / Get

Tags: c#, redis, azure-redis-cache

I have been searching for some time for a simple get / set example using C# and Azure Cache for Redis. I setup Azure Cache for Redis using default settings. I have the various Access Keys and have followed:

https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics.html

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/31866793-8064-4bce-a1e7-8bde3b793505/why-im-getting-exception-a-blocking-operation-was-interrupted-by-a-call-to-wsacancelblockingcall?forum=csharpgeneral

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-overview

But I am not able to execute s simple get / set. I have installed the various package managers. My code is below:

```
using System;
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System.Configuration;
public class Redis
{
    IDatabase db;
    public Redis()
    {
        ConnectionMultiplexer redis = "conn-string-here");
        this.db = redis.GetDatabase();
    }

    public void Set(string key, object value)
    {
        db.StringSet(key, value == null ? "" :  value.ToString());
    }

    public string Get(string key)
    {
        return db.StringGet(key);
    }
}
```

However, I keep getting this error message:

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection is
> active/available to service this operation: SET my_first_test_key; A
> blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall,
> mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: DESKTOP-78EDD5H, IOCP:
> (Busy=6,Free=994,Min=16,Max=1000), WORKER:
> (Busy=1,Free=8190,Min=16,Max=8191), v: 2.2.88.56325 --->
> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: SocketFailure on
> ZyelRedis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Subscription,
> Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: ConnectedAsync,
> outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive:
> 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat:
> never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.2.88.56325 ---> System.IO.IOException:
> Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking
> operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your connection strings. The ones that show up in Azure may not include an important part, which is: `sslprotocols=tls12`,

Example:

```
 ZyelRedis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,
 password=k7e9OS5QzZ2XQPH9NktMiHCLpN3rTcMaPAzCaP3tnC0=,
 ssl=True,
 abortConnect=False,
 sslprotocols=tls12

 Requested: sslprotocols=tls12
```